# How to playback sound and loop seamlessly under a Windows 8 Store App? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, html5-audio

I am creating a Windows 8 game (Windows 8 Store app using HTML5/JS). The problem is that sound does not loop seamlessly.

Windows 8 HTML5 does not support Web Audio (ugh!) and I cannot embed Flash Player in it as a workaround (because it is not supported in Store apps), so the only option is HTML5 audio which has a delay when looping sounds. 
I tried SoundJS but this does not help again for the above reasons.

Is there any way to play a sound looped seamlessly under a Windows 8 Store JS app?

Comment: SoundJS relies on html audios looping property (windows 8 using HTMLAudioPlugin), which should provide the smoothest possible looping in javascript.  There may be smoother native sound looping available, but its not something I know about.  Good luck.

Comment: One thing to make sure is that you've set [`msAudioCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767375.aspx) propertly, so the processing is loaded onto the right thread. If that still doesn't work, you could also try opening up the audio as a stream and repeatedly buffering the audio. I'm not sure what the performance would be like, but I'd bet that they'd be pretty good (since it's local streaming). I'm a C# developer and I believe this is possible there, not sure about JS.